# dplyr calculating new column based on filtering, group, and summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

Given `foo` below, I'm trying to calculate anomalies of `y` for three groups `id` based on the mean of a subset of `y` values. I can't see the way forward in terms of dplyr grammar but there must be a simple way.

That is, I want a way to calculate a new column `yAnom` which is `y-mean(y)` for values of `y` when `x<=5`for each `id`. Base R solution:

```
foo <- tibble(x = rep(1:10,3), y = rnorm(30), id = rep(letters[1:3],each=10))
# subtract y from mean of y for values of y when x <= 5 by group
#E.g., 
y5Means <- foo %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(x <= 5) %>% summarise(avg = mean(y)) %>% pull(avg)
foo$yAnom <- c(foo$y[foo$id == "a"] - y5Means[1],
               foo$y[foo$id == "b"] - y5Means[2],
               foo$y[foo$id == "c"] - y5Means[3])
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following:

```r
foo %>%
  # new column with only the values you want to average over, and NA elsewhere
  mutate(y_when_x_under_5 = ifelse(x <= 5, y, NA)) %>%
  # new column with mean for each group
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(y_mean = mean(y_when_x_under_5, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  # required calculation
  mutate(yAnom = y - y_mean)
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. The `ifelse` to get the right length was what I needed to make the logical jump. Thanks.